# Bot Framework Authentication not working

Tags: botframework, botconnector

**No authorisation when using "Test connection to your bot" on the bot framework portal.**

I have seen a number of questions here on the same subject, but still can't get this to work as it should. I am trying to ensure my endpoint authorisation works, but I keep getting errors...

I have followed the recommendations to the letter: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/

At first the error was;

```
InternalServerError
{
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
"stackTrace": "
```

(etc...)

I worked out that I needed to upgrade my azure plan to basic to include SSL. However, when i now test my bot connection via the bot framework portal I get;

```
InternalServerError
{
  "message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

The bot itself works fine over Skype and webchat - Its just the authorisation piece that does not want to work.

Following the link from the web app hosted on azure, proves I have an HTTPS address. The only thing I have not tried is to purchase a dedicated SSL certificate for my app.

But, surely the basic Azure plans include SSL under the generic Microsoft certificate? Any thoughts?

One final piece of info, the webchat channel for the bot constantly shows me the following issue;

```
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code
InternalServerError
```

*Azure hosting, web app, b1 basic plan...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this by a process of elimination. The bad code is below (from MessagesController.cs);

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message || activity != null)
```

While the code runs happily, the endpoint authorisation trips over when it hits;

```
activity != null
```

Therefore, by reverting to the following endpoint authorisation works;

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
```

Don't ask me how the null check was in the code, I don't know! Or why authorisation doesn't like the null check..

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the appSettings properly?

```
 <!-- update these with your BotId, Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
<add key="BotId" value="YourBotId" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="YourAppId" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="YourAppPassword" />
```

You can get these from the the [Bot Framework site](https://dev.botframework.com/bots) by editing your bot's details

Also, you do not have to purchase a dedicated SSL certificate for your app. You just have to set the Messaging endpoint with a https url (https://foobot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages)

Comment: Have definately done all of this... If I go straight to my https URL via a browser (https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/messages), i get: <Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>

Comment: @Taylor the other thing that comes to my mind is that you are not puting the [Serializable] tag in all your dialogs.

Comment: It's definitely in all the dialogs, I have a number of supporting classes.. DB access etc..